# python regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm after a regex pattern to fix a file with many screwed up tables.

The tables are supposed to be:

```
Header 1
Duration    1    2    3    4
25        1.1  2.2  3.3  4.4    
50        5.5  6.6  7.7  8.8
75        9.9  0.0  1.1  2.2
mean      5.6  6.7  9.9  9.0
Footer 1

Header 2
Duration    1    2    3    4
25        1.1  2.2  3.3  25.6
50        5.5  6.6  7.7  8.8
75        9.9  0.0  1.1  2.2
mean      5.6  6.7  9.9  9.0
Footer 2
```

But after copying and pasting from a very large PDF file, the resultant text has some new lines randomly in the middle of columns:

```
Header 1
Duration    1    2  
3    4
25        1.1  2.2  3.3  4.4    
50        5.5  6.6  7.7 
   8.8
75        9.9  0.0  1.1  2.2
mean      5.6  6.7  9.9  9.0
Footer 1

Header 2
Duration    1    2    3  
   4 
25        1.1  2.2
25.6  4.4  
50        5.5  6.6 
  7.7  8.8
75        9.9  0.0  1.1  2.2
mean      5.6  6.7  9.9  9.0
Footer 2
```

The correct lines should start either with specific headers and footers, 'Duration' and one of the statistics 25, 50, 75 and mean.

So I'm after a regex that finds all:

- new lines
- followed by a space
- or follow by any string which is NOT in a set of headers, footers, statistics.

Here is what I've come up with, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
'(\n)[^257mHDF][^05euo]'
```

Comment: [`^(?!Header|Duration|mean|Footer|[159]0)`](https://regex101.com/r/4oB0wr/1)

Comment: Or Replace each match with a blank string matched by [`[\r\n]+ *(?=\d)(?![159]0)`](https://regex101.com/r/4oB0wr/2/) with a blank string

Comment: What are you going to do with the resultant matches? If you're trying to parse the 4 values from each column, you could do that irrespective of any line breaks.

Comment: @mkrieger1 problem is that my tables have different number of columns. So that I cannot say `read 4 numbers`

Comment: @Potato Using the whole words is actually a very readable way to go, so it is working with just: `(\n) *(?!Header|Duration|Footer|mean|10 |25 |50 |75 |90 |whatever|else)`